# how to get object where any list element present in class object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

lst =  ["A","B","C","D"]

> models.py
>
> ```
> class Notice(models.Model):
>     title               = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
>     createdAt           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
>     batch               = CharField(max_length=100,default="")
> ```

how to get all object of Notice where any lst element == batch...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Notice.objects.filter(batch__in=lst)
```